# How do you find 3 UNIQUE digits in a string of digits?

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that is very specific. I want to find 3 digits in a list. The issue comes because I do not care about repeating digits (5, 555, and 55555555555555 are seen as 5). Also, within the 3 digits, they need to be 3 different digits (123 = good, 311 = bad).
Here is what I have so far to find 3 digits, ignoring repeats but it does not specify 3 unique digits.

```
^(?:([0]{1,}|[1]{1,}|[2]{1,}|[3]{1,}|[4]{1,}|[5]{1,}|[6]{1,}|[7]{1,}|[8]{1,}|[9]{1,}|[0]{1,})(?!.*\\1)){3}$<p>
```

Here is an example of the types of data I see.

Matching:

```
458
3333335555111
2222555111
222255558888
111147
9533333333
```

And not matching:

```
999999999
222252
888887
```

Right now my regex will find all of these. How can I ignore any that do not have 3 unique digits?

Comment: I very strongly suspect that a regex is not the best tool for this job...

Comment: @twalberg "very strongly" is something more than "being suspect" `:-)` it's almost confidence ..! And I agree ..!

Comment: please take a look at my answer. it solves your problem using another approach.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Understatement is the new sarcasm... ;-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your regex-tool of choice supports look-behinds, back-references and possesive matching you could use

```
^(\d)\1*+(?!.*\1)(\d)\2*+(\d)\3*+$
```

- `^` and `$` are anchors to ensure, that we check the whole string
- `(\d)` matches a digit into a first capturing group, with `\1*+` we possesively match any following occurences of this digit and use the lookbehind `(?!.*\1)` to ensure, that it doesn't end with that number.
- `(\d)\2*+` then matches the next different digit, again matching any following occurences possesively (check `122` without the possesive matching to see, why I use it here)
- `(\d)\3*+` matches the last digit with any following occurences.

Without possesive matching you could make more use of look-behinds, like `^(\d)\1*(?!.*\1)(\d)\2*(?!.*\2)(\d)\3*+$`

See https://regex101.com/r/pV2tB2/2 for a demo.

Site Note: Regex might not be the best for this, but as you specifically asked for it - here you are.

Comment: I do like this one. I will give it a shot in the morning and see how it goes.

Comment: These both seem to work the same. I am not understanding why I would want to use one over the other. I can not see where one would match but the other would not. (i.e. neither match 121, 112, 122)

Comment: They both seem to work just as I need. Also, my system may be outdated, instead of using ^(\d)\1*(?!.*\1)(\d)\2*(?!.*\2)(\d)\3*+$ can I remove the last "+" and retain the same functionality? ^(\d)\1*(?!.*\1)(\d)\2*(?!.*\2)(\d)\3*$ It does seem to work in the regex tester, but I am not sure of the logic difference between *+ and *.

Comment: @KevinBurtnett I added the second regex in case your regex-engine of choice doesn't support possesive matching - you didn't mention which tool or language you are using in the original post and not every regex-engine does support them.

Comment: @KevinBurtnett The difference between * and *+ is that * matches greedy and *+ matches possesively, you can read more [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). You are right, that you can remove the last + without changing results, the possesive matching should just be a bit quicker to fail on some samples of 4+ unique numbers, where the third is repeated multiple times and it avoids backtracking - but I doubt that it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Well, I wish I could tell you the system I am using, but that information is not available to me. The regex you provided is working beautifully. Thank you for your assistance and explanations.

Comment: @KevinBurtnett If it fully answered your question, please consider [accepting my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if an `awk` script will do it for you, but here it goes:

```
 awk '
     function match_func(num) {
         if (match_array[num] == 0)
             match_array[num] = 1;
     }
     {
         for (i = 0; i < length($1); i++)
             match_func(substr($1, i, 1));
         for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             if (match_array[i] == 1) match_sum++;
         if (match_sum == 3)
             print $1;
     }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `regex`, but it's not the best tool for your work.

Instead of a `regex-only approach`, you can easily achieve this using `Python`.

**Example**:

```
strings = ['458', '3333335555111', '2222555111', '222255558888', '111147', '9533333333', '955555555', '12222211']

for s in strings:
    if len(set(list(s))) == 3:
        print "Ok :", s
    else:
        print "Error :", s
```

Output:

```
>> Ok : 458
>> Ok : 3333335555111
>> Ok : 2222555111
>> Ok : 222255558888
>> Ok : 111147
>> Ok : 9533333333
>> Error : 955555555
>> Error : 12222211
```

I've used the following commands while iterating over the strings inside that list:

[list()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=list#list)

[set()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

[len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=list#len)

Comment: I agree the reflex is not the best tool for the job, but I am writing refer for a tool that was design before Python was popular. It only recognizes actual numbers and regex. But I will keep this in mind because I am writing a number of Python scripts now and still learning it.

Comment: I did not mean reflex, I meant regex. I guess my phone decided that regex was not the best word to use.

Answer (score 0):

Using negative lookahead, this should match any string of digits that contains at least 3 unique digits `/^(\d)\1*(?!\1)(\d)(?:\2|\1)*(?!\2|\1)(\d)+$/`

`(\d)` - Match a digit

`\1*` - Allow that digit to repeat

`(?!\1)` - Make sure that's followed by a digit that does not match the first match

`(\d)` - Match the new digit

`(?:\2|\1)*` - Allow repeats of either the first or second digit

`(?!\2|\1)` - Make sure that's followed by a digit that does not match the first or second match

`(\d)+` - Capture the third unique digit, then allow any number of digits of any kind to follow

Comment: I will try this as well. Even though my knowledge of edged has grown, these examples still blow me away with their capabilities.

Comment: This one works, but it only check the first 3 digits in a string. If the string continues then it continues to match. https://regex101.com/r/pV2tB2/3

Comment: Right, that's on purpose, I understood your question to mean that you wanted strings with at least 3 unique digits. If you want strings that only contain 3 uniques and no more than that, you'd change it to this `/^(\d)\1*(?!\1)(\d)(?:\2|\1)*(?!\2|\1)(\d)(?:\2|\1|\3)*$/`

Comment: Also, if order matters, it'd be this: `/^(\d)\1*(?!\1)(\d)(?:\2)*(?!\2|\1)(\d)(?:\3)*$/`

Comment: I am sorry. I only want 3 unique digits. So 333444555 would be good, but 345345345 would not be.